# Array of forms in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

First, thanks for taking a look at this. I am trying to create an array of forms that acts as a dynamically sized results list. From the results that were given the user can click 'detail' (a submit button) to get further information on the result which is why I am attempting to create an array of forms. Here is what I had tried, which compiled but the buttons aren't doing anything. Any help would be great :)

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<?PHP

$numbers=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$listsize=count($numbers);



for($currentnum=0;$currentnum <$listsize;$currentnum ++){
?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="button<?PHP echo $currentnum?>" />

        </form>
        <?PHP
        echo "<br/>";
    }
if(isset($_POST['button'.$currentnum])){
echo "You choose ".$currentnum;
}    
?>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is really just meant to demonstrate what I am trying to do (thought that would be easier without functions out of scope of question).

Comment: Remove the space after the $ in the name of the button, currently echo $ currentnum

Comment: Sorry about that, there isn't a space in my code, that happened while adjusting it for stackoverflow

Comment: Same for `for()` loop : `$ currentnum ++` => `$currentnum++`

Comment: Also in the "for" loop. Same problem with the spaces.

Comment: I just fixed it above (but that was a slight misstep as well when adjusting for stackoverflow) :)

Comment: Can you run the script and provide the HTML it produces? it could be an HTML issue and not a PHP issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the HTML for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="button<?PHP echo $currentnum?>" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="button<?PHP echo $currentnum?>" />
```

Close bracket for your for loop so that your check is inside it:

```
        <?PHP
        echo "<br/>";
    }
if(isset($_POST['button'.$currentnum])){
echo "You choose ".$currentnum;
}    
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php

  echo "<br/>";

  if(isset($_POST['button'.$currentnum])){
    echo "You choose ".$currentnum;
  }    
}

?>
```

If you learn to indent your code you'll find these kinds of bugs much easier to spot!

Other than that you're good to go...

Comment: I've just wanted to post the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your input types from 'button' to 'submit' so that they submit the forms, then you need to move

```
if(isset($_POST['button'.$currentnum])){
echo "You choose ".$currentnum;
}
```

inside of the for loop